# Automatically creating entry in Outlook calendar using the Exchange API

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, outlook-calendar

I am using the Exchange API to send appointment requests from any email address. Below is my code:

```c#
ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
exService.Url = new Uri("exchange URL");
exService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("userID", "password");

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exService);

appointment.Subject = "Test Subject";
appointment.Body = "test body";
appointment.Location = "Location";
appointment.Start = <Meeting start time>;
appointment.End = <Meeting end time>
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("abc@xyz.com");

appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

This code is working fine: it sends an invitation email to the attendee.

What I want to know is, is it possible to make an entry into the attendee's Outlook calendar directly, without any invitation email or any approval from the attendee?

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you impersonate the Attendee you can then accept the invitation on their behalf. See:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633648(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: I tried this. It creates calendar entry. But I can see this appointment in calender when I check on web mail but it does not download this appointment in my system's outlook(Installed application). Any workaround for this?

Comment: That doesn't sound right I would recheck your logic, try to disable cache mode in Outlook to see if that makes a difference as well. Done correctly it should work.

Comment: @SagarJoshi Which tutorial did you referred for exchange 2013 version. I mean you have added "ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);" exchange version as 2013 right, which library did you use. Even i'm trying and i can use only till exchnage version 2010 SP2. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help you.

```csh
ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
exService.Url = new Uri("exchange URL");
exService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("userID", "password");

Collection<Appointment> Meetings = new Collection<Appointment>();

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exService);

appointment.Subject = "Test Subject";
appointment.Body = "test body";
appointment.Location = "Location";
appointment.Start = <Meeting start time>;
appointment.End = <Meeting end time>
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("abc@xyz.com");
Meetings.add(appointment)

ServiceResponseCollection<ServiceResponse> responses = service.CreateItems(Meetings,WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,MessageDisposition.SendOnly,SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in addition to providing code, please also include some textual details explaining what you did and why it works.